# Changing working directory in C?

Tags: c, chdir

Im new to C and am having trouble using chdir(). I use a function to get user input then I create a folder from this and attempt to chdir() into that folder and create two more files. Howver when I try to access the folder via finder (manually) I dont have permissions. Anyway here is my code for that, any tips?

```
int newdata(void){
    //Declaring File Pointers
    FILE*passwordFile;
    FILE*usernameFile;

    //Variables for
    char accountType[MAX_LENGTH];
    char username[MAX_LENGTH];
    char password[MAX_LENGTH];

    //Getting data
    printf("\nAccount Type: ");
    scanf("%s", accountType);
    printf("\nUsername: ");
    scanf("%s", username);
    printf("\nPassword: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    //Writing data to files and corresponding directories
    umask(0022);
    mkdir(accountType); //Makes directory for account
    printf("%d\n", *accountType);
    int chdir(char *accountType);
    if (chdir == 0){
        printf("Directory changed successfully.\n");
    }else{
        printf("Could not change directory.\n");
    }

    //Writing password to file
    passwordFile = fopen("password.txt", "w+");
    fputs(password, passwordFile);
    printf("Password Saved \n");
    fclose(passwordFile);

    //Writing username to file
    usernameFile = fopen("username.txt", "w+");
    fputs(password, usernameFile);
    printf("Password Saved \n");
    fclose(usernameFile);

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: This line is pretty strange: `int chdir(char *accountType);`

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually *change* the directory, you just declare a function prototype for `chdir`. You then continue to compare that function pointer against zero (which is the same as `NULL`) which is why it fails.

You should include the header file `<unistd.h>` for the prototype, and then actually *call* the function:

```
if (chdir(accountType) == -1)
{
    printf("Failed to change directory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return;  /* No use continuing */
}
```

Comment: So if you dont mind me asking how would I change into accountType directory and create the two files that follow in the code? Sorry Im new to C. =/ and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int chdir(char *accountType);
```

is not calling the function, try following code instead:

```
mkdir(accountType); //Makes directory for account
printf("%d\n", *accountType);
if (chdir(accountType) == 0) {
    printf("Directory changed successfully.\n");
}else{
    printf("Could not change directory.\n");
}
```

also, the printf line looks suspicious, I think you want is print accountType string:

```
printf("%s\n", accountType);
```